# Get attribute of div using powershell Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I want to using powershell get Example2 from the html using Invoke-WebRequest but this does not work
Powershell:

```
$html = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://example.com"
$link = $html.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName("Example1")['0'].getAttribute("Example2)
$Reply = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $link
Write-Host $Reply
```

html:

```
<div class="Example1" Example2="https://example.com/example" b="1" a="1"</div>
```

I want it to Write-Host https://example.com/example

Comment: Hello TestSha, welcome on StackOverflow. Can you explain a bit more your problem please ? Did you have tried something or searched for an answer already, and if so, what was your problems or why that was not working ? What is exactly the problem ? "This does not work" is not very understandable.

Comment: Hello NatNgs I want to using powershell get Example2 from the html using Invoke-WebRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is basically right just a few errors

A) Dont put quotes around your index. Bad ['0'], Good [0]

B) you were missing a double quote at the **.getAttribute("Example2)** should be **.getAttribute("Example2")**

```
$html = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML"
$link = $html.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName("external")[0].getAttribute("href")
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $link
```